# Enviar datos de un datagirdview a otro

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

Hola me gustaria aprender a enviar imformacion desde mi primer datagridview a un Segundo datagridview que estaria situado en otra ventana, lo que quisiera que haga es que al dar el boton "Enviar" me envie todos los datos de la columna resultado de mi primer datagridview, espero me ayuden de antemano gracias[image: Imagen de diseño]

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del primer form, ingresa estas funciones:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.cargar(GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView1));
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
    private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (column.Visible)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add();
            }
        }

        object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Dentro del segundo form, el DataGridView deberá permanecer sin columnas, e ingresas esta función:

```
    public void cargar(DataTable dt) {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```